# What quantity remains conserved in a calorimeter when two bodies at different temperatures are mixed?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, energy-conservation

This is the question:

Two identical bodies at different temperatures are mixed in a calorimeter. Which of the following quantities remains conserved?

1) Sum of the temperatures of the two bodies
2) Total heat of the two bodies
3) Total internal energy of the two bodies
4) Internal energy of each body

As we take a calorimeter to be an isolated system, internal energy of the two bodies would remain conserved. But why won't the total heat be conserved? The principle of calorimetry states that total heat gained is equal to total heat lost. I can't figure out what I'm missing here, and I'm very confused. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think what you are missing is that asking about heat in this context makes no sense.

Comment: Yes, for something to be conserved, it must be an equilibrium physical property of the material comprising the system.  Heat is energy crossing the boundary of the system (energy in transit), and that is not a property of the material.

Comment: The principle of calorimetry assumes something like _caloric_ (or equivalently _frigoric_). That is not the right way of doing thermodynamics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heat is energy transfer between the two bodies  due solely to temperature difference between them. Once thermal equilibrium is reached between the two bodies  ( they both reach the same final temperature in the calorimeter) heat transfer between the two becomes zero. The energy that transferred results in changes in internal energy of the bodies. The energy is no longer heat. Things don’t “contain” heat.

So while you can say that the heat transferred out of one body equals the heat transferred into the other body, that’s not the same thing as saying heat is conserved. Heat is technically zero after thermal equilibrium is reached. It’s the total internal energy that  is conserved.

Hope this helps